# Final model data with Caret's train function when using rolling cross-validation with fixed window

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation, caret

According to [Caret's documentation](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#model-training-and-parameter-tuning), the `train()` function uses all training data to fit the final model when best hyper-parameters have been chosen.

However, when a **rolling cross-validation with fixed window for timeseries data is chosen**, **I don't think it makes sense to fit the final model with all the data available in the training set.** It does make sense indeed when the window is not fixed.

Just to make it clearer, I am talking about the following type of cross-validation:

```
myTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                              initialWindow = 50,
                              horizon = 1,
                              fixedWindow = TRUE)
```

My question is, does Caret really use all training data when using a fixed window to fit the final model? Is there anyway I can double check it in the model object variable?

Answer (score 1):

I found of the solution here: https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/346

This was raised as an issue on Caret's repository.

Answer (score 0):

There is another parameter for the `timeslice` method:

**skip**: *integer, how many (if any) resamples to skip to thin the total amount*

```
createTimeSlices(y, initialWindow, horizon = 1, fixedWindow = TRUE, skip = 0)
```

Take a look at: [caret documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/createDataPartition):